# window.onunload and Ajax Navigation

Tags: javascript, ajax, navigation, onunload

I'm trying to insert an onunload event into a page.

```
function onUnload(){

    console.log("GOODBYE");

    //TODO: insert Function here
}


window.onunload = onUnload;
```

It works and I am greeted Goodbye most of the time. However, there is a sidebar menu on the page that apparently implements Ajax Navigation and clicking links there doesn't trigger the onunload event.

I searched about it and based on this [link](https://www.xul.fr/ajax/ajax-navigation.php) Ajax Navigation is:

*"... allows the browser to insert in the current page the content of a page that is pointed out by a a link, when you click on this link, without refreshing the page. 
On a more general view, Ajax navigation includes back and forward functions of the browser, adapted to changing content by Ajax."*

Is there any way to call a JavaScript function whenever a redirect via Ajax Navigation happens?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried adding onclick directly to the anchor tag to call my function but it didn't work. For context, below is what the menu looks like as well as its code. The menu is auto-generated by SharePoint. I tried adding the function to the onclick of the div tag but it also didn't work

[image]

Comment: Yes, AJAX doesn't cause browser navigation and therefore no unloading occurs; it means the browser loads content from the server in the background. How to approach this depends heavily on a) what your goal is b) how the sidebar is implemented

Comment: The sidebar is automatically generated by the system which I'm building upon, which is SharePoint. What I am trying to do is just to record data into a SharePoint List whenever the user leaves a page for tracking purposes.

Comment: I guess you could add your own click handler to the sidebar buttons?

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. Let me update my question with info on what I tried because I'm not sure if it was the right way to do it.

Comment: Can you try putting `onclick="alert('Test')"` so we can make sure the onClick is being called in the first place?

Comment: I tried out the alert onclick for the Documents and it worked. When I replaced the alert with my function instead, I get the error message in console: SCRIPT5007: Object expected script block (892) (2,1) … as well as a warning:  SEC7131: Security of a sandboxed iframe is potentially compromised by allowing script and same origin access.